# Derived class not inheriting overloaded method from base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading, shadowing

I would like to have a method in a base class call a pure virtual method that will be implemented in a derived class. However, the base class parameterless method doesn't seem to be inherited by the derived class. What am I doing wrong? Compiler is MSVC12.

> error C2660: 'Derived::load' : function does not take 0 arguments

Here is a complete example (that doesn't compile due to the error):

```
struct Base
{
    void load() { load(42); }; // Making this virtual doesn't matter.
    virtual void load(int i) = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual void load(int i) {};
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.load(); // error C2660: 'Derived::load' : function does not take 0 arguments
}
```

Comment: @Deduplicator Wish I could +1 an edit.

Comment: You are quite welcome, as it was only final polishing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oh, the derived class **does** inherit `void load()`.

But you are declaring `void load(int i)` in the derived class, which means it is shadowed.

Add `using Base::load;` to `Derived` to add all non-overridden definitions of `load` from `Base` to the overload-set in `Derived`.

Alternatively, call the `Base`-class-version explicitly with the scope-resolution-operator `d.Base::load();`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the `Base` one explicitly: `d.Base::load();`. I have no idea why, but it works. My guess is that overriding hides all overloads.